# Extracting each ZIP files in folder A to a separate folders (Folders are manually created and they existed)

Tags: powershell

I have PowerShell 4.0 and windows server 2012 R2. I want to extract ZIP files (84 files) to a separate folders. I create a script that work fine but it is hard-coded and the code is too long to troubleshoot. I want to reduce the code by parameterizing the script to reduce the numbers of lines of code. Can anyone help me with this?  Here is my script:

```
Function Get-ShortName {
begin {
$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject }
process {
If ($_.psiscontainer) {
$fso.getfolder($_.fullname).ShortName }
ELSE {
$fso.getfile($_.fullname).ShortName }
} }

#Formatting today's date
$TodayDate = (Get-Date).ToString('DTyyMMdd')

#Formatting the first day of the month
$Year = (get-date).Year
$Month = (get-date).Month
$FirstDayMth = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day 1
$FirstDayOfMonth = $FirstDayMth.ToString('DTyyMMdd')

#Download Nightly and Monthly files
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\users\in\FileZIP*_nightly.$TodayDate" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files" -Force -Verbose 
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\users\in\FileZIP*_monthly.$FirstDayOfMonth" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files" -Force -Verbose

#Unzip files
Add-Type --AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip {
param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath) }

#Check if files exist
$checkprovfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files -File
if ($checkprovfiles.Count -eq 84 ) {
echo "Files have been downloaded SUCCESSFULLY. Now we need to Extract them"

Get files shortname
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files\*.*" | Get-Shortname
Foreach ($file in $files) {
if ($file -eq "FileZIP1_nightly.$TodayDate") {
echo 'Start extracting FileZIP1 nightly files'
Unzip ""C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files\FileZIP1_nightly.$TodayDate" "C:\data_files\Extracted_files\FILEZIP1_Nightly_Monthly_Extracted\"
echo 'Finish extracting FileZIP1 nightly files' }

if ($file -eq "FileZIP1_monthly.$FirstDayOfMonth") {
echo 'Start extracting FileZIP1 monthly files'
Unzip ""C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files\FileZIP1_monthly.$FirstDayOfMonth") "C:\data_files\Extracted_files\FILEZIP1_Nightly_Monthly_Extracted\" 
echo 'Finish extracting FileZIP1 monthly files'

if ($file -eq "FileZIP2_nightly.$TodayDate") {
echo 'Start extracting FileZIP2 nightly files'
Unzip "C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files\FileZIP2_nightly.$TodayDate" "C:\data_files\Extracted_files\FILEZIP2_Nightly_Monthly_Extracted\"
echo 'Finish extracting FileZIP2 nightly files'

if ($file -eq "FileZIP2_monthly.$FirstDayOfMonth") {
echo 'Start extracting FileZIP2 monthly files'
Unzip ""C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files\FileZIP2_monthly.$FirstDayOfMonth") "C:\data_files\Extracted_files\FILEZIP2_Nightly_Monthly_Extracted\"
echo 'Finish extracting SFileZIP2 monthly files' }
.
.
.
if ($file -eq "FileZIP84_nightly.$TodayDate") {
echo 'Start extracting FileZIP84 nightly files'
Unzip "C:\data_files\Provisioning_Files\FileZIP84_nightly.$TodayDate" "C:\data_files\Extracted_files\FILEZIP84_Nightly_Monthly_Extracted\"
echo 'Finish extracting FileZIP84 nightly files' }
}
else {
echo "Provisionning files are incomplete or could not be found on ." 
EXIT }
```

I repeated the IF statement 84 times and I dont want to do that. It is hard to troubleshoot. I want to reduce the if statement and I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me or have a suggestion to do the script another way?

Answer (score 0):

This shows as a lot of stuff going on here, for such a simple task and those zip file names, do not have a zip extension, and thus are not seen by the file system as zip files. Yet, that's your choice of course.

I'd suggest moving that date string to the files base name and using the normal zip extension, meaning to the left of the period. It makes doing what you are after easier, otherwise you have extra work to handle the non-normal extension. Such as that extra file rename thing you appear to be doing.

Anytime you get beyond 3 - 5 if statements, it's time to leverage a 'Switch' instead. See the sample snippets provided in the ISE for that idea or …

```
Get-Help -Name About_Switch -Examples
Get-Help -Name About_Switch -Full
Get-Help -Name About_Switch -Online
```

With this many selections though it's probably time to rethink your approach.

The below is untested, since I have no file types like what you show, so tweak as needed.

For the destination and unzip use case. Try something like this as a baseline to get 
you started. Of course add any additional error / message / string name handling you require.

```
# Unpack archives from source to destination
Function Expand-ZipFile 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('ezf')]

    <# 
    Set parameters to allow for passing in the function call
    or if a parameter is not passed, prompt the use for it.
    #>

    Param
    (
        [String]$SourcePath = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the full path of a root source folder'),
        [String]$DestinationPath = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the full path to the root destination folder.')
    )

    # Initialize the .Net compression namespace
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem


    # Get all zipfiles in a source folder.
    'Collecting all the zip files from the source folder.'
    $ZipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter '*.zip'

    ForEach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles)
    {
        <#
        Set the destination name using the destination path and add a sub folder 
        using the basename of the zip file
        #>
        'Initializing zip destination path'
        $ZipPath = New-Item -Path "$DestinationPath\$($ZipFile.BaseName)" -ItemType Directory -WhatIf

        # Extract to zip destination path
        "Extacting zip file to the zip destination path names: $ZipPath"
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($($ZipFile.FullName), $($ZipPath.FullName))
    }
}

# .Example use case
Expand-ZipFile -SourcePath 'D:\SourcePath' -DestinationPath 'E:\DestinationPath'
```

***Update for the OP***

As for …

> Could you please give me some example on how to apply REGEX or
>   SUBSTRING with the function above.

Outside or inside the function, it's just piping in the file, then apply the string extract.

```
'FILE1ZIP_nightly_yyyyddmm', 'FILE1ZIP_monthly_yyyymmdd' | %{$_.SubString(0,8)}
FILE1ZIP
FILE1ZIP
```

Comment: Can anyone help me how to extract nightly zip and monthly zip files into one destination like nightly_monthly_extracted_folder?

Comment: As for this … (Is it possible in Powershell to use ZipFile.basename.SubString(0,8) to get the first 8 characters of FILE1ZIP) … yes, using RegEx or substring

Comment: Could you please give me some example on how to apply  REGEX or SUBSTRING with the function above. For example I have 2 files (FILE1ZIP_nightly_yyyyddmm and FILE1ZIP_monthly_yyyymmdd) that I want to have the first 8 caracteres. FILE1ZIP which is 8 characters long will be the destination path to extract nightly and monthly files. How can I do this?

Comment: 'FILE1ZIP_nightly_yyyyddmm', 'FILE1ZIP_monthly_yyyymmdd' | %{$_.SubString(0,8)}
FILE1ZIP
FILE1ZIP..... FILE1ZIP is returned twice because there are 2 filenames. I want to have the FILE1ZIP to be returned only once because it will be the extraction destination folder. How will do that?

Comment: Then just drop one of them or add a select statement to grab only the first one. Meaning... | Select -First 1

Comment: How do I accomplish this with the function above?I don't want to use the zipfile.basename. Thank you.Below are the filenames.                                                                                    aco00_monthly.out.DT190301 and 
aco00_nightly.out.DT190312 ...                                                                    should be extracted into folder aco_nightly_monthly_extracted

 ...atn00_monthly.out.DT190301 and 
atn00_nightly.out.DT190312 ..                                                                    Should be extracted into folder atn_nightly_monthly_extracted